# Random orthogonal, 90 degrees rotation with ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

I use following code to train my CNN model with invoice images.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator( 
                rescale = 1. / 255, 
                 shear_range = 0.2, 
                  zoom_range = 0.2, 
            horizontal_flip = True
            ) 

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1. / 255) 

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir, 
                              target_size =(img_width, img_height), 
                     batch_size = batch_size) 

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory( 
                                    validation_data_dir, 
                   target_size =(img_width, img_height), 
          batch_size = batch_size) 

model.fit_generator(train_generator, 
    steps_per_epoch = nb_train_samples // batch_size, 
    epochs = epochs, validation_data = validation_generator, 
    validation_steps = nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
```

The problem is I used only upright images in my training data set. All my images are like following image:

[image: An upright image that was used during the training]

After the training when I want to send an image like below, my model fails to predict its right class.

[image: wrong predicted image]

As you see below, I send horizontal_flip = True to ***ImageDataGenerator***

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator( 
                rescale = 1. / 255, 
                 shear_range = 0.2, 
                  zoom_range = 0.2, 
            horizontal_flip = True
            )
```

How can I change my code so that it can predict even flipped images. Or should I use manually flipped images within my training dataset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would rotate the images randomly with `ImageDataGenerator`. Just specify the following argument:

> rotation_range: Int. Degree range for random rotations.

Or, you can pass a preprocessing function to `ImageDataGenerator` which gives you more flexibility.

```
def orthogonal_rot(image):
    return np.rot90(image, np.random.choice([-1, 0, 1]))

train_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=orthogonal_rot)
```

This function will rotate by either -90, 0, or 90 degrees.

(The `np.rot90()` function is rotating the image 90 degrees times the second parameter. Accordingly -1 is -90 degrees, 0 is no rotation, 1 is 90 degrees and 2 would be 180 degrees.)

Comment: Thank your for your answer. But how can I set rotation_range value. I want to rotate 90 degrees right and left. So should I set 90?

Comment: yes but i believe this will rotate from [-90, 90], hope that's okay

Comment: This rotates my images between -90 and 90(various rotations). But how can I set function to only rotate +90 and -90 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

If you need right angle rotations only, it can be set with a preprocessing function that uses the keras `apply_affine_transform` function. Then, you can pass the preprocessing function to the `ImageDataGenerator` via the `preprocessing_function` argument. Using this approach, you can also go with the same `fill_mode` for the right rotation and the data generation.

[Documentation apply_affine_transform](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/apply_affine_transform)
[Documentation ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator)

```py
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import apply_affine_transform

FILL_MODE = 'nearest'

def right_angle_rotate(input_image):
    angle = random.choice([0, 90, 180, 270])
    if angle != 0:
        input_image = apply_affine_transform(
            input_image, theta=angle, fill_mode=FILL_MODE)
    return input_image

data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
    fill_mode=FILL_MODE,
    preprocessing_function=right_angle_rotate)
```

However, the `numpy.rot90` function will cause an exception, if your input images are rectangle images, as the input size will not match after 90° and 270° rotations.